# Efficiently split Tensorflow models over multiple GPUs

Tags: tensorflow

I'm training very large models using Tensorflow, splitting the model over multiple GPUs. For simplicity, let's say it's 100 convolution layers one after another. Currently, I have 4 GPUs: layers 1-25 placed on GPU0, layers 26-50 on GPU1, and so on. My average GPU utilization over all 4 GPUs is roughly only 33% each. I assume this is due to the GPUs having to wait for the previous GPUs to finish calculations on its layers.

What is the best way to increase the GPU utilization and speed up training?